# Colorize FlowDocument

Tags: c#, flowdocument

I'm using C# 3.0 and I have following FlowDocument:

```
var doc = new FlowDocument();
var p = new Paragraph();
p.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello 777 world 777"));
doc.Blocks.Add(p);
```

How can I wrap all "777" substrings with Hyperlink programmaly?
I need to get a document, where all "777" were hyperlinks.

Comment: Hyperlinks are blue, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be old, but for people who will have the same issue.

```
var doc = new FlowDocument();
var p = new Paragraph();
p.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello "));
p.Inlines.Add(new Hyperlink(new Run("777")));
p.Inlines.Add(new Run(" world "));
p.Inlines.Add(new Hyperlink(new Run("777")));
doc.Blocks.Add(p);
```